# SQL 2005 User Instances and SQL Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-authentication, user-instance

Can I use SQL Authentication with User Instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**No:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684(SQL.90).aspx)

> Limitations When Using User Instances
>
> - User Instance does not
>   support SQL Server Authentication.
>   Only Windows Authentication is
>   supported.